# I have to search for all city name starting with vowel words but array pattern is not working for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Query the list of CITY names ending with vowels (a, e, i, o, u) from STATION. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

```
select distinct(city)
from station 
where city like "%A" or city like "%E" or city like "%I" or city like "%O" or city like "%U"
```

The above code is working properly.
But I don't know why below code is not working

```
select distinct(city)
from station 
where city like "%[AEIOU]"
```

I tried REGEXP_LIKE as well but not getting error.
I am using MySQL

Comment: select distinct(city) from station where city like REGEXP "[AEIOU]$"

Comment: Because MySQL does not support character classes in `LIKE`.  And no city name ends in`[AEIOU]`.

Comment: @Chandan The code is not working

Comment: @GordonLinoff No actually as I said I am getting output with first query , so I guess LIKE is working in MySQL and we have city name with [AEIOU] as well

Comment: @AnubhavSrivastava I forgot to remove "like" from your original query. This should work - select distinct(city) from station where city REGEXP "[AEIOU]$"

Comment: @Chandan Thanks , it's resolved . Could you please share some document where I will get more info about pattern in MySQL because MySQL documentation is not that helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT city FROM table_name WHERE substr(city,1,1) in('a','e','i','o','u');
```